# How to save react context data so that it persists after refreshing the page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using react hooks and context api . I get a user info. when i log in, which was null by default in the context. But when i refresh the page the value does not persist in the context api . How can i save the user info. ?

```
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,

  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Persist it to localStorage upon state change. Use an initializer function when the context mounts to read from localStorage and initialize your reducer state. If you need more help from here I can provide guidance.

Comment: Did you initialize state from localStorage? That's part of the solution of persisting app state for page reloads.

Comment: i solve this like this
 useEffect(() => { 
     if (state.user!==null) {
      
        localStorage.setItem("currentuser", JSON.stringify(state.user));
       
     }
  }, [state]) ; 
so now i can use currentuser

Comment: i don't know how to initialize state from localStorage

Comment: That is covered in the linked answer in the "Round out the rest of the app" section.